# Should drag interaction start on mouse over or on click?

Tags: graphs, interactive-ui

I have an interactive graph that shows info on a timeline. The user drags a handle over this timeline to show events for every date on it. The thing is that this graph is only on part of the viewport, among other interactions (forms, buttons, etc).

My question is: should I start drag on mouse over (the graph) or on drag/click (handle/timeline)?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say **Point and Click** as opposed to mouse over. Positioning and controlling the graph is easier with click. 
Wichita state university **[conducted a study](http://usabilitynews.org/mouse-over-vs-point-and-click-it-depends/)** on mouse-over vs click and a majority of test participants indicated that they felt more in control with point-and-click. 
Results also indicated that the mouse-over technique took significantly longer than the traditional point-and-click technique.

P.S : There's also an interesting paper on this topic - **[The Effects of selection technique on target acquisition movements made with a mouse.](http://pro.sagepub.com/content/42/5/473.short)** However, I'm unable to get a full copy of it.

Comment: Very interesting study on click making users feel more in control, I was going to include something about me feeling more in control/precise with click and drag than mouseover but omitted it because I couldn't quantify it.

Comment: Ya, the study is interesting. However,I really wanted to go through that paper, but it's behind a pay wall :(  There's also a good book on this topic - https://books.google.co.in/books?id=clLlBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=The+Effects+of+Selection+Technique+on+Target+Acquisition+Movements+Made+with+a+Mouse&source=bl&ots=qDjXnUuotV&sig=MfLcQMiLbBTur4YeOy-_MB63Y3s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBmoVChMI5safsavixgIVS5mACh1mCAdM#v=onepage&q=The%20Effects%20of%20Selection%20Technique%20on%20Target%20Acquisition%20Movements%20Made%20with%20a%20Mouse&f=false

Comment: The alternative to drag on hover would be drag handle as well as click on the timeline. The main question being if the drag behaviour works better if the user actively selects the handle and pulls it or if the handle grabs on to the cursor on mouse over. Does that study provide insights on that kind of behaviour?

Comment: The study shows that click and select is preferred over mouse over. Although, the use case is different here, what remains true is that user will have better control over the interaction when he selects and pulls it.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of personal opinion, definitely on click. I can see several reasons why:

1. What if the user needs to position the graph at a certain point and then type about what the data it shows in a textbox elsewhere. They will mouseover until they have the correct data, then when they mouseoff to focus the text field the graph will follow their cursor changing the data and forcing them to restart.
2. Same concept if they want to position the graph timeline at the beginning but then mouseover certain parts of the graph to point out data in a part of a presentation. The timeline would try to follow their cursor to that point.
3. What about touch screens/mobile? Mouseover is much less intuitive when there is no mouse, yet dragging works well on both touchscreen and mouse environments.

Comment: Your first point makes most sense in this particular application's context. The user loses reference for an event if he chooses to input data on a nearby field. As for mobile interaction, the touchscreen version of this application is touch and drag only.